# Adding a string for the join condition on SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, articles and log. I'm trying to join the two tables a look only for the articles that appear in the log. The only relation that the two tables have is articles.slug which shows the title of the article and log.path which shows the same text of articles.slug but with '/article/' at the beginning. Exmaple:

This is the log.path: '/article/bad-things-gone'
This is the articles.slug: 'bad-things-gone'

I'm trying to do this:

```
        SELECT articles.title, count 
        FROM articles join
             (SELECT path, COUNT(*) as count 
              FROM log
              GROUP BY path
              ORDER BY count desc
             ) as a
             ON ('/article/' + articles.slug) = a.path
```

but it is not working as it says I can not add the string '/articles/' to the articles.slug.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  The error seems pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
        SELECT a.title, l.count 
        FROM articles a join
             (SELECT l.path, COUNT(*) as count 
              FROM log l
              GROUP BY l.path
             ) l
             ON ('/article/' || a.slug) = l.path
        ORDER BY l.count desc;
```

Notes:

- Postgres uses the standard operator `||` for string concatenation.
- Ordering in a subquery has nothing to do with ordering in the outer query.
- Use table aliases that relate to the table name or subquery.
- Qualify all column names.

Answer (score 0):

use the CONCAT function

SELECT CONCAT('/article/', column);